# SQL - Copy records but change a value if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Profile.Profiles) with 3 columns (UserType, ProfileId, Description) and here's a sample of the values

```
'Regional' 'Arrow-MEDIUM' 'This is a description'
'Regional' 'Arrow-HIGH' 'This is a description'
'Regional' 'Show-MEDIUM' 'This is a description'
'Regional' 'Table-MEDIUM' 'This is a description'
'Regional' 'Table-LOW' 'This is a description'
'Regional' 'Borrow-MEDIUM' 'This is a description'
'Regional' 'Answer-MEDIUM' 'This is a description'
'Regional' 'Rope-MEDIUM' 'This is a description'
'Regional' 'Rope-HIGH' 'This is a description'
```

I need to DUPLICATE the rows with the ending 'MEDIUM' but change the word 'MEDIUM' to 'HIGH'. So for example this is one record that would need to be created:
'Regional' 'Show-HIGH' 'This is a description'

I've tried a few ways to do it but can't get it to work.

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Profile.Profiles
            WHERE ProfileId LIKE '-MEDIUM')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Profile.Profiles
        SELECT UserType, REPLACE(ProfileId, '-MEDIUM', '-HIGH'), Description)
            FROM Profile.Profiles
            WHERE ProfileId LIKE '%-MEDIUM';
    END
END
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: @user5171795 - I think your insert statement has an extra `)` after `Description`

Comment: Sorry it's SQL Server

Comment: I don't think your If statement would ever be false with the code how it's written. The existing -MEDIUM records would still be there afterward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `INSERT` should work fine without an `IF`:

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a767f/1)**</kbd>

```
INSERT INTO Profile.Profiles(UserType, ProfileId, Description)
    SELECT UserType, REPLACE(ProfileId, '-MEDIUM', '-HIGH'), Description
    FROM Profile.Profiles
    WHERE ProfileId LIKE '%-MEDIUM';
```

The `IF` causes the `INSERT` not to be run because rows exist with `-MEDIUM`.

EDIT:

If the `ProfileId` is supposed to be unique, then do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Profile.Profiles(UserType, ProfileId, Description)
    SELECT UserType, REPLACE(ProfileId, '-MEDIUM', '-HIGH'), Description
    FROM Profile.Profiles p
    WHERE ProfileId LIKE '%-MEDIUM' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Profile.Profiles p2
                      WHERE p2.ProfileId = REPLACE(p.ProfileId, '-MEDIUM', '-HIGH')
                     );
```

Note:  If you unique constraint/key includes more columns, then you need to include them in the nested `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Tried that first and I was getting duplicate error. "Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Profile.Profiles'". That's why I tried adding the IF NOT EXISTS section

Comment: Tried the second version and didn't work. It executed successfully but it didn't create any new records

Comment: @user5171795 . . . It is a table alias which is important for correlated subqueries.  For example, I left out the table alias on `ProfileId` which was incorrect.

Comment: WOOHOO IT WORKED!!!!! I put the other alias in and worked beautifully! Thanks heaps for that! :)